# Ejabberd auth http query to django server unauthenticated

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, ejabberd

I am trying to use [ejabberd_auth_http](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/ejabberd_auth_http) module for user authentication in ejabberd server. Hence, for authentication, ejabberd server (http://localhost:5222) will make a query to django rest server and check if the user exist with provided credentials. The GET requests handler in django server is as follows.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def user_exists(request):
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=request.query_params.get("user"))
        return Response({"user_exists": True})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise exceptions.NotFound(False)


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def check_password(request):
    try:
        User.objects.get(Q(......))
        return Response({"check_password": True})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(False)
```

Whenever I am trying to login to ejabberd web admin (http://localhost:5280/admin/) it does makes a query to rest server but the rest server returning unauthorized (HTTP 401) response. The follow is the response log in django server side.

```
"GET /ejabberd/check_password?user=772&server=192.168.1.102&pass=password HTTP/1.1" 401 59
```

However, if I use resulting url http://localhost:8000//ejabberd/check_password?user=772&server=192.168.1.102&pass=password in a **browser** HTTP response 200 is received.

Is django-rest is using any kind of build in  protection for cross server query? If so, how to allow query for the ejabberd server.

Following is the code snippet of setting.py

```
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Rest Framework app
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    # Internal Apps
    'itiData',
    'ejabberd',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I guess ejabberd_auth_http sends Basic Authorization header with url. Using `@authentication_classes([])` in the django functional view could able to get rid of the problem.